# useContext: Components are calling the default values of the functions defined in the file where I created the context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I created a file `CartContext.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Product } from "../models/ProductModel";

interface CartContextValue {
  cart: Product[];
  addOneProductToCart: (product: Product) => void;
  removeOneProductFromCart: (productId: number) => void;
  deleteAllProductsFromCart: () => void;
}

export const CartContext = React.createContext<CartContextValue>({
  cart: [],
  addOneProductToCart: (product: Product) => {}, <----- **This runs in ShopPage**
  removeOneProductFromCart: (productId: number) => {},
  deleteAllProductsFromCart: () => {},
});

export const CartProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState<Product[]>([]);

  const addOneProductToCart = (product: Product) => { <----- **This should run instead!**
    setCart([...cart, product]);
  };

  const removeOneProductFromCart = (productId: number) => {
    const updatedCart = cart.filter((product) => product.id !== productId);
    setCart(updatedCart);
  };

  const deleteAllProductsFromCart = () => {
    setCart([]);
  };

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider
      value={{
        cart,
        addOneProductToCart,
        removeOneProductFromCart,
        deleteAllProductsFromCart,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I am using the Provider in `App.js` such that all my components gets access to the data:

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet, setupIonicReact } from "@ionic/react";
import { IonReactRouter } from "@ionic/react-router";
import { NavBar } from "./components/NavBar/NavBar";
import "@ionic/react/css/ionic.bundle.css";
import { useContext } from "react";

/* Pages */
import { UploadPage } from "./pages/UploadPage";
import { HomePage } from "./pages/HomePage";
import { ShopPage } from "./pages/ShopPage";
import { WatchVideoPage } from "./pages/WatchVideoPage";
import { LoginPage } from "./pages/LoginPage";
import { SuccessPurchasePage } from "./pages/SuccessPurchasePage";
import CancelPurchasePage from "./pages/CancelPurchasePage";
import { RegisterPage } from "./pages/RegisterPage";
import { CartContext } from "./state/CartContext";
// Custom styles
import "./theme/variables.css";
import "./theme/styles.css";

setupIonicReact();

const App: React.FC = () => {
  **const {
    cart,
    addOneProductToCart,
    removeOneProductFromCart,
    deleteAllProductsFromCart,
  } = useContext(CartContext);**
  
  return (
    <IonApp>
      **<CartContext.Provider
        value={{
          cart,
          addOneProductToCart,
          removeOneProductFromCart,
          deleteAllProductsFromCart
        }}
      >**
        <IonReactRouter>
          <NavBar />
          <IonRouterOutlet>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/video/:name" component={WatchVideoPage} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
            <Route exact path="/upload" component={UploadPage} />
            <Route exact path="/success" component={SuccessPurchasePage} />
            <Route exact path="/cancel" component={CancelPurchasePage} />

            <Route exact path="/shop" render={() => <ShopPage />} />
          </IonRouterOutlet>
        </IonReactRouter>
      **</CartContext.Provider>**
    </IonApp>
  );
};
export default App;
```

I have a component/page, where I want to add one product to the cart which is in the context I created `ShopPage.tsx`:

```
import {
  IonPage,
  IonContent,
  IonHeader,
  IonTitle,
  IonToolbar,
  IonCard,
  IonCardHeader,
  IonCardTitle,
  IonCardContent,
  IonGrid,
  IonRow,
  IonCol,
  IonButton,
  IonSpinner,
} from "@ionic/react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import useProducts from "../hooks/useProducts";
import { Product } from "../models/ProductModel";
import { CartContext } from "../state/CartContext";

export const ShopPage = () => {
  const [products, isLoading, isError] = useProducts();
  **const { addOneProductToCart } = useContext(CartContext);**
  
  if (isLoading) {
    return <IonSpinner name="circular" />;
  }

  if (isError) {
    return <h1>Could not get items...</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Shop</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
        <div className="ion-padding-horizontal ion-padding-top">
          <h1 className="ion-no-margin">Shop</h1>
        </div>
        <IonGrid>
          <IonRow>
            {Array.isArray(products) &&
              products.map((product: Product) => {
                return (
                  <IonCol
                    key={product.id}
                    size="12"
                    size-sm="12"
                    size-md="6"
                    size-lg="4"
                  >
                    <IonCard>
                      <img src={product.image} alt="Product" />
                      <IonCardHeader>
                        <IonCardTitle>{product.name}</IonCardTitle>
                      </IonCardHeader>
                      <IonCardContent>
                        <p>{product.description}</p>
                        <IonButton
                          className="float-right ion-margin-bottom"
                          color="dark"
                          **onClick={() => addOneProductToCart(product)}**
                        >
                          Buy
                        </IonButton>
                      </IonCardContent>
                    </IonCard>
                  </IonCol>
                );
              })}
          </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

The cart does not get updated.

**I do not see the point with having to use `useContext` in `App.js` and then passing the value in to the Provider. It is very confusing. There has to be something I have misunderstood.**

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, But try this! Should work :

1. Remove this line

```
import { CartContext } from "./state/CartContext"
```

2. Add import for **CartProvider**
3. Then instead of

```
    <CartContext.Provider
            value={{
              cart,
              addOneProductToCart,
              removeOneProductFromCart,
              deleteAllProductsFromCart
            }}>
```

**Put this**

```
<CartProvider>
     **Rest of code**
</CartProvider>
```

Comment: ``'CartContext' is not defined.eslintreact/jsx-no-undef``
I get this in ``App.js``

Comment: Could you reproduce this in sandBox?